# Adding Class Name in JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json

I created below JSON  of Person class using JSON.NET But "Person" is not showing up anywhere in JSON. I think it should show up in the start. What is the problem or how to resolve? Thank you.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Umer",
    "Age": 25
  },
  {
    "Name": "Faisal",
    "Age": 24
  }
]
```

C# code is here which generated JSON

```
List<Person> eList = new List<Person>();
Person a = new Person("Umer",25);
Person b = new Person("Faisal", 24);
eList.Add(a);
eList.Add(b);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList,Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144300/json-net-class-name-as-root

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `TypeNameHandling` setting:

```
List<Person> eList = new List<Person>();
Person a = new Person("Umer", 25);
Person b = new Person("Faisal", 24);
eList.Add(a);
eList.Add(b);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

This way each JSON object will have an additional field "$type":

```
[
    {
        "$type" : "YourAssembly.Person"
        "Name" : "Umer",
        "Age" : 25
    },
    ...
]
```

For more details see [the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in that.It can be deserialized that way.

You can deserialize it like that :

```
Person deserialized = (Person)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( serializedText ,typeof(Person))
```

But if you need the root [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name) question may help.

Comment: He's not asking about deserialisation, from what I gather he wants the root of the json to start with the word Person

Answer (score 1):

You could use anonymous class to recreate your list and then serialize it if you really want class name as part of your JSON.

```
var persons = eList.Select(p => new { Person = p }).ToList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

[image: JSON image]

Comment: Wouldn't just `eList.Select(p => new { Person = p })` suffice? We know that each person object is serialized properly. We just need to key each object to the string "Person". Please correct me if I missed something.

Comment: @AmithGeorge You're absolutely right. I edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var Person = new List<Person>();
Person a = new Person("Umer", 25);
Person b = new Person("Faisal", 24);
Person.Add(a);
Person.Add(b);

var collection = Person;
dynamic collectionWrapper = new {
  myRoot = collection
};

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
```

Comment: in the line `var collection = Person`, did you mean to instead type `"Person"`, ie a string?